# How can I stop django REST framework to show all records if query parameter is wrong

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST Framework and i am using filters to filter the query set.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters

like this

`http://example.com/api/products/4675/?category=clothing&max_price=10.00`

But i have seen that if there is error in filters or the query parameters does not exist then it displays all results which is very bad.

I rather want no results if there is issue with query parameters because sometimes i don't know if that is working or not

EDIT

This is my code

```
class userFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    strict = True

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('is_active', 'is_archived', 'age')
```

REST

```
class UserListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.filter(is_archived=False)
    ordering_fields = ('is_active')
    filter_class = userFilter
```

This is REST settings

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_MODEL_SERIALIZER_CLASS':
        'rest_framework.serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer',
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',
        'rest_framework.filters.SearchFilter',
        'rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter',
    ),
    # 'PAGINATE_BY': 1,                 
    'PAGINATE_BY_PARAM': 'page_size',  
    'MAX_PAGINATE_BY': 100,             
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Comment: you should post your code.. it will make sense after looking at it.. if you are literally following the link you refers .. it will result in giving all results as it returns a queryset which was initialized to objects.all, rather u shoul check for query_params and if not correct return None .. for better answer spit out your code !

Comment: @vijayshanker hi vijay, i have added the code. please have a look

Comment: override get_queryset method.. and look for QUERY_PARAMS in request to narrow down the results.. this should do

Comment: take a look at this: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the [DjangoFilterBackend](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend), take a look at the [strict Non-Meta option](https://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#strict).

> The strict option controls whether results are returned when an
>   invalid value is specified by the user for any filter field. By
>   default, strict is set to True meaning that an empty queryset is
>   returned if any field contains an invalid value. You can loosen this
>   behavior by setting strict to False which will effectively ignore a
>   filter field if its value is invalid.

**The filter:**

```
from django_filters.filterset import FilterSet

class UserFilter(FilterSet):
    strict = True

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username']
```

**The settings:** (assumes you have installed [django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter))

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',)
}
```

Now, if someone does:

```
http://api.example.com/users/?username=myuser&badfilter=1
```

...it will return an empty list, as `badfilter` does not exist.

As the [`FilterSet`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#the-filter) automatically defaults to `strict=True`, I have a feeling that you are not taking advantage of the `DjangoFilterBackend`.

Comment: @Michale, I tried that and it still shows me all records. I think there is some setting REST rather than  in filters. Can you please check

Comment: I would need to see your settings for `REST_FRAMEWORK` from your settings file. Sorry for the delayed reply.

Comment: I have added my REST settings. please have a look. i am stuck at this

Answer (score 3):

The marked answer didn't work for me. I solved it by overriding the "get" method:

```
class UserListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.filter(is_archived=False)
    ordering_fields = ('is_active')
    filter_class = userFilter

    @staticmethod
    def is_valid_query_params(query_params):
        # do validations here
        ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.is_valid_query_params(request.query_params):
            return Response([])  # send empty response 
        return super(UserListCreateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Same case here. For those using ModelViewSet instead of generics, keep in mind that you should override `list` instead of `get`. The problem is that in that case you need to override the other method (actions) as well (retrieve, update, etc..) :(

Comment: I liked overriding the get_queryset more (personal preference).

Answer (score 2):

Your specific issue arises from the fact that the parameters you invoke in your GET query are not defined in your `UserFilter`. Thus only the following parameters will be taken into account from DRF:

```
fields = ('is_active', 'is_archived', 'age')
```

Moreover `strict` only controls the **value** of a query parameter, **not if the parameter itself exists**. For example

```
GET mydomain.com/resource_path?whatever=blabla
```

returns the whole queryset which is something wrong in my opinion, at least not REST-compliant.

I ended up writing a small method to manually check if the query parameters passed in the request actually exist.

Comment: This answer is really important -- `strict` only controls the VALUE!  https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/860#issuecomment-360048454

Answer (score 1):

I did this by overloading the function get_queryset() in class which inherit generics.ListAPIView. You can check params with self.request.query_params , and write custom handler for any cases.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the author](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/860#issuecomment-360048454), `strict` only filters the *values* assigned to the query parameters, not the *existence* of the query parameters.

Otherwise things such as paging, which add its own query parameters, would break the API.

You can override `get_queryset()` to validate the query keys:

```
class List(generics.ListAPIView):       

    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()                                          
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer                                       
    filter_fields = ('q1', 'q2',)
    # or filter_class

    def get_queryset(self):
        paging = set(['limit', 'offset'])
        qs = super(RestrictedQueryMixin, self).get_queryset()
        # Optional mutual exclusion check below...
        if hasattr(self, 'filter_fields') and hasattr(self, 'filter_class'):
            raise RuntimeError("%s has both filter_fields and filter_class" % self)
        if hasattr(self, 'filter_class'):
            filter_class = getattr(self, 'filter_class', None)
            filters = set(filter_class.get_filters().keys())
        elif hasattr(self, 'filter_fields'):
            filters = set(getattr(self, 'filter_fields', []))
        else:
            filters = set()
        for key in self.request.GET.keys():
            if key in paging:
                continue
            if key not in filters:
                return qs.none()
        return qs
```

I made this into a mixin.

Alternatively, you could raise `rest_framework.exceptions.APIException`.  You can also alternatively get the  paginator fields dynamically from `self.paginator.get_schema_fields(self)`

Comment: Note that if you are using django-rest-swagger you will need to add 'format' to the list of keys you ignore.

Comment: Funny you should mention that -- I had to do just that the other day!